# Flutter apply method to static variable

Tags: flutter, variables, methods, static

How do you apply a method to a static variable from a class. There are certain built in classes in flutter that appear to do something like this.

```
class UITextStyle {
  static const TextStyle body = TextStyle(fontSize: 17);

   addColor(Color color) {
    TextStyle style = this as TextStyle;
    style.merge(TextStyle(color: color));
  }
}
```

Which can then be called like this:

```
UITextStyle.body.addColor(Color.fromRGBA(0,0,0,1));
```

However I cannot call that method like that as firstly it is not static, and secondly if it were I would not be able to call it after declaring `.body` first and would only be able to call it at `UITextStyle.addColor(...)`.

How is this achieved?

Comment: how does it differ from `void main() {
Foo.foo.bar('hello world');
}
class Foo {
static final foo = Foo();
bar(String s) {
print(s);
}
}` ?

Comment: ahh, you mean you have `const` while I have `final`?

Comment: Not quite. I am simply trying to write cleaner code. I could build the above class differently but you the ability to use methods this way with classes like CupertinoColors and CupertinoDynamicColor. A  CupertinoDynamicColor can be declared as a static variable and then additional methods can be added in line, for example: CupertinoColors.activeBlue.resolveFrom(context).withOpacity(0.8); I am trying to also be able to add methods after the static variable exactly like that.

Comment: Your code works for that print statement. I cannot apply it to merging a text style. If I take the static variable of body, I cannot apply the method to it. Your code appears to only implement the class rather than the static variable.

Comment: Think I've got it. Thanks for your code, it gave me some good hints of what to look for.

Comment: Can you provide an example where you've seen that?  Usually `this as TextStyle` cannot work when `this`'s class (`UITextStyle`) is not related to `TextStyle`.  An exception would be if `UITextStyle` is used only as a mixin on a `TextStyle`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can try this solution , the point is that addColor function is not defined to the TextStyle Type , so to achieve that you need to add this function to the TextStyle class by this extension :

```
extension TextStyleEx on TextStyle{

  TextStyle addColor(Color color) {
    return merge(TextStyle(color: color,fontWeight: FontWeight.w600));
  }

}
```

and make this method return TextStyle so you can get instance from the merged ones , cause your static object is final so you can not receive new value on it.

- and leave your class like this

  ```
    class UITextStyle {
      static const TextStyle body = TextStyle(fontSize: 17);
    }
  ```
- use this class and the saved static object to get new TextStyle with the old and the new TextStyles.
- for test run this in main , will clear the previous example :

  ```
  TextStyle mergedStyles = UITextStyl.body.addColor(Colors.black);
  print(mergedStyles);
  ```

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to the comments from @pskink I was eventually able to get this functioning.

```
class UITextStyle {
  const UITextStyle(this.style);
  final TextStyle style;
  static const body = UITextStyle(TextStyle(fontSize: 17));

  addColor(Color color) {
    TextStyle textStyle = style;
    return textStyle.merge(TextStyle(color: color));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In Dart `extensions` can have static members.

```dart
extension UITextStyle on TextStyle {
  static const body = TextStyle(fontSize: 17);
  
  TextStyle addColor(Color color) {
    return this.merge(TextStyle(color: color));
  }
}
```

```dart
UITextStyle.body.addColor(Color.fromRGBO(0, 0, 0, 1));
```